# Sort By Date last created and limit to five result

Tags: php

I am trying to do two things one is to Sort By Date last created the next one is to limit the the amount of data show to five (5) so ticket one, ticket two, ticket three, four, and five

I am making a drop down window that shows the last 5 ticket that was created and i am getting the information from below

Thank you for your help

```
   <?php
    if(!defined('OSTCLIENTINC') || !is_object($thisclient) || !$thisclient->isValid()) die('Access Denied');

    $qstr='&'; //Query string collector
    $status=null;
    if(isset($_REQUEST['status'])) { //Query string status has nothing to do with the real status used below.
        $qstr.='status='.urlencode($_REQUEST['status']);
        //Status we are actually going to use on the query...making sure it is clean!
        switch(strtolower($_REQUEST['status'])) {
         case 'open':
         case 'closed':
            $status=strtolower($_REQUEST['status']);
            break;
         default:
            $status=''; //ignore
        }
    } elseif($thisclient->getNumOpenTickets()) {
        $status='open'; //Defaulting to open
    }

    $sortOptions=array('id'=>'`number`', 'subject'=>'subject.value',
                        'status'=>'ticket.status', 'dept'=>'dept_name','date'=>'ticket.created');
    $orderWays=array('DESC'=>'DESC','ASC'=>'ASC');
    //Sorting options...
    $order_by=$order=null;
    $sort=($_REQUEST['sort'] && $sortOptions[strtolower($_REQUEST['sort'])])?strtolower($_REQUEST['sort']):'date';
    if($sort && $sortOptions[$sort])
        $order_by =$sortOptions[$sort];

    $order_by=$order_by?$order_by:'ticket_created';
    if($_REQUEST['order'] && $orderWays[strtoupper($_REQUEST['order'])])
        $order=$orderWays[strtoupper($_REQUEST['order'])];

    $order=$order?$order:'ASC';
    if($order_by && strpos($order_by,','))
        $order_by=str_replace(','," $order,",$order_by);

    $x=$sort.'_sort';
    $$x=' class="'.strtolower($order).'" ';

    $qselect='SELECT ticket.ticket_id,ticket.`number`,ticket.dept_id,isanswered, '
        .'dept.ispublic, subject.value as subject,'
        .'dept_name,ticket. status, ticket.source, ticket.created ';

    $dynfields='(SELECT entry.object_id, value FROM '.FORM_ANSWER_TABLE.' ans '.
             'LEFT JOIN '.FORM_ENTRY_TABLE.' entry ON entry.id=ans.entry_id '.
             'LEFT JOIN '.FORM_FIELD_TABLE.' field ON field.id=ans.field_id '.
             'WHERE field.name = "%1$s" AND entry.object_type="T")';
    $subject_sql = sprintf($dynfields, 'subject');

    $qfrom='FROM '.TICKET_TABLE.' ticket '
          .' LEFT JOIN '.DEPT_TABLE.' dept ON (ticket.dept_id=dept.dept_id) '
          .' LEFT JOIN '.TICKET_COLLABORATOR_TABLE.' collab
            ON (collab.ticket_id = ticket.ticket_id
                    AND collab.user_id ='.$thisclient->getId().' )'
          .' LEFT JOIN '.$subject_sql.' subject ON ticket.ticket_id = subject.object_id ';

    $qwhere = sprintf(' WHERE ( ticket.user_id=%d OR collab.user_id=%d )',
                $thisclient->getId(), $thisclient->getId());

    if($status){
        $qwhere.=' AND ticket.status='.db_input($status);
    }

    $search=($_REQUEST['a']=='search' && $_REQUEST['q']);
    if($search) {
        $qstr.='&a='.urlencode($_REQUEST['a']).'&q='.urlencode($_REQUEST['q']);
        if(is_numeric($_REQUEST['q'])) {
            $qwhere.=" AND ticket.`number` LIKE '$queryterm%'";
        } else {//Deep search!
            $queryterm=db_real_escape($_REQUEST['q'],false); //escape the term ONLY...no quotes.
            $qwhere.=' AND ( '
                    ." subject.value LIKE '%$queryterm%'"
                    ." OR thread.body LIKE '%$queryterm%'"
                    .' ) ';
            $deep_search=true;
            //Joins needed for search
            $qfrom.=' LEFT JOIN '.TICKET_THREAD_TABLE.' thread ON ('
                   .'ticket.ticket_id=thread.ticket_id AND thread.thread_type IN ("M","R"))';
        }
    }

    $total=db_count('SELECT count(DISTINCT ticket.ticket_id) '.$qfrom.' '.$qwhere);
    $page=($_GET['p'] && is_numeric($_GET['p']))?$_GET['p']:1;
    $pageNav=new Pagenate($total, $page, PAGE_LIMIT);
    $pageNav->setURL('tickets.php',$qstr.'&sort='.urlencode($_REQUEST['sort']).'&order='.urlencode($_REQUEST['order']));

    //more stuff...
    $qselect.=' ,count(attach_id) as attachments ';
    $qfrom.=' LEFT JOIN '.TICKET_ATTACHMENT_TABLE.' attach ON  ticket.ticket_id=attach.ticket_id ';
    $qgroup=' GROUP BY ticket.ticket_id';

    $query="$qselect $qfrom $qwhere $qgroup ORDER BY $order_by $order LIMIT ".$pageNav->getStart().",".$pageNav->getLimit();
    //echo $query;
    $res = db_query($query);
    $showing=($res && db_num_rows($res))?$pageNav->showing():"";
    $showing.=($status)?(' '.ucfirst($status).' Tickets'):' All Tickets';
    if($search)
        $showing="Search Results: $showing";

    $negorder=$order=='DESC'?'ASC':'DESC'; //Negate the sorting

    ?>
    <h1>Tickets</h1>
    <br>
    <form action="tickets.php" method="get" id="ticketSearchForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="a"  value="search">
        <input type="text" name="q" size="20" value="<?php echo Format::htmlchars($_REQUEST['q']); ?>">
        <select name="status">
            <option value="">&mdash; Any Status &mdash;</option>
            <option value="open"
                <?php echo ($status=='open')?'selected="selected"':'';?>>Open (<?php echo $thisclient->getNumOpenTickets(); ?>)</option>
            <?php
            if($thisclient->getNumClosedTickets()) {
                ?>
            <option value="closed"
                <?php echo ($status=='closed')?'selected="selected"':'';?>>Closed (<?php echo $thisclient->getNumClosedTickets(); ?>)</option>
            <?php
            } ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Go">
    </form>
    <a class="refresh" href="<?php echo Format::htmlchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">Refresh</a>
    <table id="ticketTable" width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <caption><?php echo $showing; ?></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="70" nowrap>
                    <a href="tickets.php?sort=ID&order=<?php echo $negorder; ?><?php echo $qstr; ?>" title="Sort By Ticket ID">Ticket #</a>
                </th>
                <th width="100">
                    <a href="tickets.php?sort=date&order=<?php echo $negorder; ?><?php echo $qstr; ?>" title="Sort By Date">Create Date</a>
                </th>
                <th width="80">
                    <a href="tickets.php?sort=status&order=<?php echo $negorder; ?><?php echo $qstr; ?>" title="Sort By Status">Status</a>
                </th>
                <th width="300">
                    <a href="tickets.php?sort=subj&order=<?php echo $negorder; ?><?php echo $qstr; ?>" title="Sort By Subject">Subject</a>
                </th>
                <th width="150">
                    <a href="tickets.php?sort=dept&order=<?php echo $negorder; ?><?php echo $qstr; ?>" title="Sort By Department">Department</a>
                </th>
                <th width="100">Phone Number</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
         if($res && ($num=db_num_rows($res))) {
            $defaultDept=Dept::getDefaultDeptName(); //Default public dept.
            while ($row = db_fetch_array($res)) {
                $dept=$row['ispublic']?$row['dept_name']:$defaultDept;
                $subject=Format::htmlchars(Format::truncate($row['subject'],40));
                if($row['attachments'])
                    $subject.='  &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="Icon file"></span>';

                $ticketNumber=$row['number'];
                if($row['isanswered'] && !strcasecmp($row['status'],'open')) {
                    $subject="<b>$subject</b>";
                    $ticketNumber="<b>$ticketNumber</b>";
                }
                $phone=Format::phone($row['phone']);
                if($row['phone_ext'])
                    $phone.=' '.$row['phone_ext'];
                ?>
                <tr id="<?php echo $row['ticket_id']; ?>">
                    <td class="centered">
                    <a class="Icon <?php echo strtolower($row['source']); ?>Ticket" title="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>"
                        href="tickets.php?id=<?php echo $row['ticket_id']; ?>"><?php echo $ticketNumber; ?></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<?php echo Format::db_date($row['created']); ?></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<?php echo ucfirst($row['status']); ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="tickets.php?id=<?php echo $row['ticket_id']; ?>"><?php echo $subject; ?></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<?php echo Format::truncate($dept,30); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $phone; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }

         } else {
             echo '<tr><td colspan="7">Your query did not match any records</td></tr>';
         }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php
    if($res && $num>0) {
        echo '<div>&nbsp;Page:'.$pageNav->getPageLinks().'&nbsp;</div>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Hi, what is your question?

Comment: @Axarydax I am trying to Sort By Date last created the next one is to limit the the amount of result show to five

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: @Steve the code is in tickets.php  I am inputting the code into my header.php file but the result is coming up more then 5 and its not showing from the last one created

Comment: have you tried echoing $query to see what it is that you are actually sending to the db?

Comment: All the information is showing just want to limit the number of ticket showing up and show only last 5 created

Answer (score 0):

```
$limit='';
$i=0; 
$q=mysql_query(...)
while($i<=mysql_num_rows($q))
{
$b=$i+5;
$limit='limit '.$i.', '.$b;
mysql_query(...$limit)
}
```